# Can someone help debug this Select Case

Tags: vba

I've been at this for a little while, with no succes.

It won't show any other result, except for the first two cases and the last one.

I have tried an less than or equal to case.

```
        Dim DayLeft As Long
        DaysLeft = Me.Days.Value

        Select Case DaysLeft
            Case Is = 0
                MsgBox "Deadline due today!"
            Case Is < 0
                MsgBox "Deadline expired!"
            Case 90 To 31
                MsgBox "First notice " & Me.Days& " days until deadline!"
            Case 30 To 11
                MsgBox "Deadline due soon! " & Me.Days & " days until deadline!"
            Case Is <= 10
                MsgBox "Warning! " & Me.Days& " days until deadline!"
        End Select
```

Comment: `DaysLeft`/`DayLeft`   Another Option Explicit use case....

Comment: 31 to 90, 11 to 30.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) documentation:

> The `To` keyword specifies a range of values. If you use the `To` keyword, the smaller value must appear before `To`.

So you need

```
Case 31 to 90
...
Case 11 to 30
```

Answer (score 3):

These two are illegal:

> ```
>     Case 90 To 31
>         MsgBox "First notice " & Me.Days& " days until deadline!"
>     '...
>     Case Is <= 10
>         MsgBox "Warning! " & Me.Days& " days until deadline!"
> ```

The `&` operator in `Me.Days&` gets interpreted as a *type hint*, not a string concatenation operator: it needs a leading space!

```
        Case 90 To 31
            MsgBox "First notice " & Me.Days & " days until deadline!"
        '...
        Case Is <= 10
            MsgBox "Warning! " & Me.Days & " days until deadline!"
```

Without that space, your code won't compile ("Syntax Error").

[Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) picks up two [unreachable Case clauses](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/UnreachableCase), which are unreachable for the reason highlighted in [BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58223904/1188513).

[image: Rubberduck inspections showing undeclared DaysLeft variable and unreachable Case blocks]

Note that it also warns about `DaysLeft` being undeclared, and `Option Explicit` not being specified.